# C++ plugin architecture in Linux environment

Tags: c++, linux, plugins, vtable

I always get the below error message :

```
error: undefined reference to 'vtable for a'
```

when I try to do `a *ker = (a *)create_a_dll();`

how to fix this problem ??

here are my definitions.

```
class base {...};

class a : public base {...};

extern "C" 
{
    base *create_a_dll()
    {
        return new a();
    }
}


class b : public base {...};

extern "C" 
{
    base *create_b_dll()
    {
        return new b();
    }
}
```

any information would be appreciated !!!!

thanks

Comment: Strange pointer type C-style casting here `a *ker = (a *)create_a_dll();` is a less strange thing in that line of code. But what if u use 'return new a;' without operator() bracers?

Comment: What is in the `...`for class `a`?

Comment: to vard,
well, I fix the problem...
just my mistake...the error not complain the create_a_dll...but the next line I try to use a->do_something(), and the do_something I didn't add virtual modifier in the header file.

to Drax,
the ... just means do something.

thanks ur information